# EC KeyPairGenerator not available. newbie developer here

Tags: kotlin

***Exporting Encrypted Key Failed***

Unable to export encrypted key, please fix the issues and try again.  Details: EC KeyPairGenerator not available.
*

I am building an app in android studio, it appears after i click release on `aab format.`
is there anyone experiencing the same?

Perhaps they can help me.. thank you

I tried to export in different name and different file location. but it does not really help